# What table holds the category selections for the time_card table in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

I'm using the ODBC connector to query time card data from the `time_card` table in ServiceNow, and there are two columns I'm wondering about: `category` and `dv_category` - those two fields are pulled from somewhere, and I do not know where.  Is there are table that holds these values, or are they static on the UI and passed through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'category' field is just a string(40) with a Choice List local to the field.  So, it's not a reference field, just a drop down.  The Choice List can be modified

I'm not finding the 'dv_category' field on the time_card table and I'm on Helsinki Patch 3.  Can you clarify?

Editing to add the actual answer to the question : 'I believe the table you're looking for is called 'sys_choice''

Comment: I'm aware of all this ('dv_category' shows the display value of the selected category). I was told by someone the dropdown values should be in a table somewhere.  And your question should not be in an answer. ;)  I'm not sure the version.  The company I work for uses the online one at company.service-now.com (unless the sub-domain is pointing to an install on company servers; I have no idea). This is my first time dealing with all this, and the db looks like a horrid mess the way it's built, lol.

Comment: Understood.  I'm a bit new here :)  I believe the table you're looking for is called 'sys_choice'

Comment: Congrats, you found it. ;) Seems this worked for me: `SELECT *
FROM  sys_choice where name='time_card' and language='en'`